# Loading animation and locked all elements on page

Tags: css, animation

I have added on my site loading animation prepared in CSS code. I have a problem because when the animation ends it all on the page is locked and nothing can be a click away.

```
.loader2 {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 400; 
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: loader2 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-animation: loader2 2s linear 0s;
  -o-animation: loader2 2s linear 0s;
  animation: loader2 2s linear 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader2{ 0%{ background-color: #0000FF; opacity: 1;  } 
100%{ background-color: #ffffff; opacity: 0; }}
```

and in html (at the bottom of the code): `<div class="loader2"></div>`

I solved this problem, but it adds additional animations, which I do not need.

```
@-webkit-keyframes loader2{ 0%{ background-color: #0000FF; opacity: 1; width: 100%;  }
100%{ background-color: #ffffff; opacity: 0; width: 0%; }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the `z-index` property on the last keyframe, setting a negative value

```
@-webkit-keyframes loader2{ 
   0%    { background-color: #0000FF; opacity: 1; z-index: 400; } 
   99.9% { background-color: #ffffff; opacity: 0; z-index: 400; }
   100%  { z-index: -1; } 
}
```